# Convention of using #includes for the header files for using a system call provided by linux kernel into my custom system call

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linker, system-calls, header-files

I am trying to design a system call of my own. And as per need, I am considering using a system call already provided by linux kernel. Below is the program :

```c
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/syscalls.h>
#include <linux/cpu.h>
#include <linux/sched/isolation.h>
//#include <../tools/include/nolibc/sys.h>

SYSCALL_DEFINE1(my_test, int , cpuid){
    
    umode_t m=0;
    int fd=sys_open("abc.txt", O_RDWR, m);
    sys_write(fd, "I AM ABHISHEK\n", 14);
    // remove_cpu(cpuid);
    // //printk("This message is printed from a system call by Abhishek Ghosh");
    // housekeeping_isolcpus_setup("domain,managed_irq,0");
    // housekeeping_nohz_full_setup("0");
    // add_cpu(cpuid);
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to achieve something as the following as given above. Open a file, in the context of the process which calls it. `fd` shall index into the open-file table of the process, which calls my system call. And then using that `fd`, I try to write a string to it.

`arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl`, mentions that `sys_open` is the 2nd syscall in the table. Also, `sys_write` is the 1st syscall in the table.

`include/linux/syscalls.h` has

```c
asmlinkage long sys_open(const char __user *filename,
                int flags, umode_t mode); //line 1089
```

and

```c
asmlinkage long sys_write(unsigned int fd, const char __user *buf,
              size_t count); //line 500
```

In spite of including `#include <linux/syscalls.h>` while compiling the kernel I get the following errors:

```
my_syscalls/my_test.c: In function ‘__do_sys_my_test’:
my_syscalls/my_test.c:9:12: error: implicit declaration of function ‘sys_open’; did you mean ‘seq_open’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
    9 |     int fd=sys_open("abc.txt", O_RDWR);
      |            ^~~~~~~~
      |            seq_open
my_syscalls/my_test.c:10:5: error: implicit declaration of function ‘sys_write’; did you mean ‘ksys_write’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   10 |     sys_write(fd, "I AM ABHISHEK\n", 14);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~
      |     ksys_write
```

My custom system call definition is written in a directory under the folder `linux-6.0.19`, and I have added the required other modification.

The definition of the required `sys_open` and `sys_write` are present in `tools/include/nolibc/sys.h`, but when I include that header, after making modifications to the line :

`#include <stdarg.h>` ---------> `#include <linux/stdarg.h>`

The situation becomes even worse. Many constants like `O_RDWR` etc get redefined, and many issues come concerning incomplete structure definition and conflicting structure definition...

I am a beginner in linux kernel programming. Please can you guide me, as to how to use the #includes in this case?

I mean instead of having the function declaration in `include/linux/syscalls.h`, why the compiler says `implicit declaraction` ?

---

```c
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/syscalls.h>
#include <linux/cpu.h>
#include <linux/sched/isolation.h>
// #include <../tools/include/nolibc/sys.h>
extern asmlinkage long sys_write(unsigned int fd, const char __user *buf,
              size_t count);

extern asmlinkage long sys_open(const char __user *filename,
                int flags, umode_t mode);

SYSCALL_DEFINE1(my_test, int , cpuid){
    
    umode_t mode=0;
    int fd=sys_open("abc.txt", O_RDWR,mode);
    sys_write(fd, "I AM ABHISHEK\n", 14);
    // remove_cpu(cpuid);
    // //printk("This message is printed from a system call by Abhishek Ghosh");
    // housekeeping_isolcpus_setup("domain,managed_irq,0");
    // housekeeping_nohz_full_setup("0");
    // add_cpu(cpuid);
    return 0;
}
```

Using `extern` declaration in the beginning, resolves the `implicit declaration` error, but now there is a link time issue, `undefined reference`.

```
abhishek@abhishek:~/OS_Proj/linux-6.0.19_full_fledged_backup$ make -j16
  DESCEND objtool
  CALL    scripts/atomic/check-atomics.sh
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  CHK     include/generated/compile.h
  CC      my_syscalls/my_test.o
  AR      my_syscalls/built-in.a
  CHK     kernel/kheaders_data.tar.xz
  GEN     .version
  CHK     include/generated/compile.h
  UPD     include/generated/compile.h
  CC      init/version.o
  AR      init/built-in.a
  LD      vmlinux.o
  MODPOST vmlinux.symvers
  MODINFO modules.builtin.modinfo
  GEN     modules.builtin
  LD      .tmp_vmlinux.kallsyms1
ld: my_syscalls/my_test.o: in function `__do_sys_my_test':
/home/abhishek/OS_Proj/linux-6.0.19_full_fledged_backup/my_syscalls/my_test.c:15: undefined reference to `sys_open'
ld: /home/abhishek/OS_Proj/linux-6.0.19_full_fledged_backup/my_syscalls/my_test.c:16: undefined reference to `sys_write'
ld: /home/abhishek/OS_Proj/linux-6.0.19_full_fledged_backup/my_syscalls/my_test.c:15: undefined reference to `sys_open'
ld: /home/abhishek/OS_Proj/linux-6.0.19_full_fledged_backup/my_syscalls/my_test.c:16: undefined reference to `sys_write'
make: *** [Makefile:1169: vmlinux] Error 1
abhishek@abhishek:~/OS_Proj/linux-6.0.19_full_fledged_backup$
```

Comment: The _undefined reference_ at link time means that your compiler cannot find the function definition corresponding to a prototyped symbol you have created.

Comment: @ryyker please can you help resolve it? I have not dealt with such a huge code base before... pointers to resolve it I mean..

Comment: Is the .c file that is used to contain the function that corresponds with the symbol prototyped in the header file included in your compile command?

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, the function definition of sys_open and sys_write are present inside a sys.h header. (path is mentioned in the question), but when I include it in my my_test.c containing my custom system call shown above, the situation further breaks. Like there is redefinition of many macros and even variables. I am wondering that since the definition of those functions are in a sys.h header, if the header is not used anywhere, then no object code is created containing sys_open or sys_write. But I wonder, if that is the case, how are the sys_open and sys_write calls implemented

Comment: I think you need to use the `filp_open()`, `filp_close()` and `kernel_write()` functions declared by `#include <linux/fs.h>`.

Comment: @IanAbbott Thanks for the pointers, trying to look into it

Comment: Note that if you had looked for the _definition_ of `sys_open` [and _not_ just the prototype], it would be in `fs/open.c`. The definition of `filp_open` is in that file too. A little bit of reading would have helped. `sys_open --> do_sys_open --> do_sys_openat2 --> do_filp_open`. `do_filp_open` is in `fs/namei.c` The comment on `filp_open`:  **This is the helper to open a file from kernelspace if you really
 * have to.  But in generally you should not do this, so please move
 * along, nothing to see here..**

Comment: Also node that `filp_open()` returns an error number encoded as a pointer value if it fails, so the result of `filp = filp_open( ... )` needs to be checked for error with `if (IS_ERR(filp)) {` `/* handle error here */` `} else {` `/* handle successful open here */` `}`.